# Can't Compile SDL2 For 32-Bit on 64-Bit Ubuntu Using Arm GNU Toolchain

Tags: c, arm, cross-compiling, sdl-2, cortex-a

**Background**

I am trying to cross compile SDL2 using the [Arm GNU Toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/arm-gnu-toolchain-downloads). My host is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS running on WSL and my target is a 32-bit Cortex-A7. I have successfully compiled and ran "Hello World" with this setup, so my next step is to compile "Hello World" while including SDL2. Here's the file:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>
int main()
{
  printf("Hello SDL2");
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the command I am using:

```
<path-to-compilers>/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -static hellosdl2.c -o hellosdl2 -I /usr/include/SDL2 -I /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu -DSDL_DISABLE_IMMINTRIN_H
```

I am able to avoid the classic `"No such file SDL2.h"` error message by including the install paths of the 64 and 32 bit versions of the SDL2. (Downloaded using `apt-get install libsdl2-dev libsdl2-dev:i386`) I am also able to avoid the error `"immintrin.h: No such file or directory"` by using the `-DSDL_DISABLE_IMMINTRIN_H` flag.

**Problem:**

I cannot resolve this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_stdinc.h:90,
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_main.h:25,
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL.h:32,
                 from hellosdl2.c:2:
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls-helper-functions.h:20:40: error: ‘_Float128’ is not supported on this target
   20 | __MATHDECL_ALIAS (int, __fpclassify,, (_Mdouble_ __value), fpclassify)
```

It looks like the SDL2 library is configured to build for a 64-bit target, and the compiler keeps catching that. I believe I'm missing a flag or a dependency. I have perused the interwebs for information on compiling SDL2 on a 32-bit target but haven't seen this situation anywhere.

Comment: You are including the folder ``/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu``, and the error you get seems to be from a file coming from this folder. But as that folder's name imply (``i386-linux``), it's not meant for ARM, but for Intel processors. You're including the wrong folder. Additionally, you don't seem to link the SDL2 library in your building command here. You're supposed to compile SDL2 beforehand into a dynamic or static library, and THEN to link it to your Hello World project.